# Is there a block that represents 'void' in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the void consist of blocks that are different to air blocks? If not, then is it possible to make one, say, with mods?

I'm experimenting with various block types. If void blocks exist, I'd like to place a void block outside of the void.

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer:

There is no void block.

Long Answer:

The void block does not exist simply because the void is just the point at which the world does not generate, and, as such, it is only air. The game itself detects you at a position at which it knows the void is in and deals damage accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Since 1.13 there are two new types of air: `cave_air` and `void_air`. Cave air is generated in most parts of caves and void air is used internally for some purpose for the regions below y=0 and above y=256. You can set both with commands, but they behave identical to regular `air` (except for `/execute if block` and similar of course). Void air does not deal damage, it is only the fact of being below y=-64 that deals damage.

The only thing that deals damage in the same way as the void is the command `/kill`. If you want to emulate something similar, the best you can do is to manually place void air or anything else and then let a command repeatedly give the player an instant damage effect whenever they are inside it. The cause of death will be different, but you can turn off death messages and print your own using `/tellraw`.

Answer (score 2):

No, such block does not exist in vanilla minecraft. If you want to search through all the blocks that DO exist, visit this website:

[Minecaft IDs](http://minecraft-ids.grahamedgecombe.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean portal blocks? Like the end_gateway block? You can't obtain it, but you can use /setblock to place it though